# Method in Java to create a file at a location, creating directories if necessary?

Tags: java, file-io, cross-platform

I am attempting to write a file using java.io, where I am trying to create it at the location `"some/path/to/somewhere/then-my-file"`. When the file is being created, any of the directories on the path may or may not exist. Rather than throw an IOException because there are no such directories, I would like the directories to be created transparently, as and when required.

Is there a method that will create any directories required on the way to writing a file? I am looking for something within the Java SDK, *or* within a lightweight library I can add to the classpath, e.g. Apache Commons IO.

P.S. For clarity's sake, I have already coded a solution, which works for the fairly narrow way I'm testing it, so I don't really need suggestions on how to write the method I'm looking for. I'm looking for a method which will have been fairly well tested, and cross-platform.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`new File("some/path/to/somewhere/then-my-file").getParentFile().mkdirs()`

Comment: Note that mkdirs() doesn't throw an IOException if it can't create the directories, it just returns false.  It's a good idea to check that the directory already exists, or was created successfully.    If (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) throw new IOException("Could not create directory " + dir);

Comment: Yup, fair point. You can get into some fairly unpleasant logic there, such as the parent existing but not being a directory, or existing and not being writeable, etc.

Comment: Oh wow, I wrote about 10 lines of code to try to get the parent directory, independent of the system, but `System.lineSeparator` gave something that apparently didn't work well with `replaceAll` because of String vs. Regex and so on, I even used horrible Regex like this: `separator=File.separator.replaceAll("'","\\\\'").replaceAll("\\\\","\\\\\\\\").replaceAll("\\\"","\\\\\"");` And it still didn't work right. But apparently there's a builtin, I should have seen this coming.

Answer (score 3):

Since the question also mentioned the library **Apache Common IO**, I report in the following a solution that uses this nice library:

```
File file = new File("...  the directory path ..."); 
FileUtils.forceMkdir(file);
```

This solution uses the class [`FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html), from package `org.apache.commons.io` and the method [`forceMkdir`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#forceMkdir%28java.io.File%29), that "*Makes a directory, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories*".

Comment: TS wants make a _regular_ file. Then it would be like `FileUtils.forceMkdir(regularFile.getParentFile())` or `FileUtils.forceMkdirParent(regularFile)` since version 2.5

Comment: Good catch! Feel free to edit the answer to improve it. Comments are often non-read

Answer (score 2):

Guava also has [Files.createParentDirs(File)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#createParentDirs%28java.io.File%29).